# ZeroMQ: How to initialize a SUB and PUSH socket in same code? i.e. black box pattern but not using different machines

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I have this code

```
context = zmq.Context()

app_worker = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
app_worker.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9005")

app_sub = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
app_sub.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9004")
app_sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'sometopic')

while True:
    msg = app_sub.recv()
    msg_data = msg.split(' ',1)
    app_worker.send_json(msg_data[1])
    print msg_data[1]
```

but when i run this, it is unable to receive any message from the publisher but when i comment this lines

```
app_worker = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
app_worker.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9005")
```

it suddenly works. it is stated in the zeromq guide chapter 5 black box pattern that this is possible. if so, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get an error message or it just hangs? How many instances of this code do you execute?

Comment: there is no error message. since it is in an infinite loop, it goes in the loop but i suppose is unable to receive any message.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply enough data to solve this question with 100% assurances.

But based on what you did post the most obvious problem is that the port 9005 was already binded by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Its very likely your `app_worker.send_json(msg_data[1])` is blocking (the entire thread) if there are no downstream nodes to PULL the messages.

Set the `send_json` to non blocking mode and check the error/exception returned

`app_worker.send_json(msg_data[1], zmq.NOBLOCK)`

The reason it "works" when you comment out the `bind` is because the send is just failing and not blocking.